# Guardar Datos provenientes de una consulta y mostrar en tabla en PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

el siguiente código es para realizar una consulta y presentármela en forma de tabla en código PHP, lo que deseo saber es que si esta consulta a la misma vez de presentarmela puedo ir guardandola en otra tabla de un HTML o PHP para ir acumulando las consultas del dia, y al mismo tiempo guardarla en una tabla de MYSQL, atento a sus consejos, de antemano muchas gracias!

```html
<?php

    function ejecuta_consulta($labusqueda)
    {


        $conexion= mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Fallo al conectar con la base de datos";
            exit();
        }

        mysqli_select_db($conexion, "gym") or die("No se encuentra la base de datos.");


        $consulta = "select * FROM pagosclientes  where idCliente like '%$labusqueda%' ";

        $resultados = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

        $filas = array(); // Crea la variable $filas y se le asigna un array vacío
        // (Si la consulta no devuelve ningún resultado, la función por lo menos va a retornar un array vacío)

        while ($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($resultados, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            $filas[] = $fila; // Añade el array $fila al final de $filas
        }

        mysqli_close($conexion);

        return $filas; // Devuelve el array $filas
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Sistema de historias médicas - Dr. Darling Davila</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <?php
        $mibusqueda=$_GET["buscar"];

        $mipag=$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];

        if ($mibusqueda!=null) {
            $pacientes = ejecuta_consulta($mibusqueda);
    ?>

        <div id="main-container">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>idPagoCliente</th>
                        <th>idCliente</th>
                        <th>idTipoPeriodo</th>
                        <th>inicio</th>
                        <th>final</th>
                        <th>costo</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                    // Si la variable $pacientes esta definida y no está vacía
                    if (isset($pacientes) && !empty($pacientes)) {
                        // Recorre cada $paciente dentro del array $pacientes
                        foreach ($pacientes as $paciente) {
                            ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['idPagoCliente'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['idCliente'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['idTipoPeriodo'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['inicio'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['final'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['costo'] ?></td>

                        </tr>
                    <?php
                        }
                    } ?>
                </tbody>
        </div>
    <?php
        } else {
            echo ("<form action='". $mipag . "' method='GET'>

                    <h2>Busqueda de paciente</h2>
                    <div class='contenedor'>
                    <input type='text' name='buscar' class='input-100 text-center inline-block col-md-6 btn-enviar espacio-arriba'></label>

                    <input type='submit' name='enviando' value='Consulta' class='text-center inline-block col-md-12 espacio-arriba btn-enviar'>
                </div>
                </form>");
        }
     ?>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Si, si se puede, la pregunta es ¿como lo quieres guardar exactamente?. PD: Tu query es muy vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL, usa consultas preparadas.

Comment: Hola, estoy aprendiendo apenas y pues estará en un entorno controlado (localmente sin internet) planeo después mejorarlo para el tema de inyeción, por ahora lo que deseo es funcionalidad, cuando me dices que como lo quiero guardar, no logro entender a que te refieres, Muchas Gracias!

Comment: Me refiero al formato con el que lo quieres guardar en la BBDD

Comment: Pensaba guardarlo en una tabla con cada campo similar si es VARCHAR que así sea y al final añadiendo un campo que de como igualdad a la fecha de HOY() , espero responderte a la pregunta y gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Vale, ¿Si recuperas n registros guardas n registros?

Comment: así mismo, poder guardar todos los datos que realice mi consulta.

Comment: Pues con un INSERT SELECT despues de hacer tu consulta te valdria. Si los datos pueden variar entre tu consulta y este Insert yo usaría transacciones. Ejemplo de como es un INSERT SELECT en Mysql -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391344/insert-with-select

Comment: Hola, ya lo intente y si me funcionó de maravilla, puedes publicarlo como respuesta para así votarla?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta sería

```html
<?php

    function ejecuta_consulta($labusqueda)
    {


        $conexion= mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Fallo al conectar con la base de datos";
            exit();
        }

        mysqli_select_db($conexion, "gym") or die("No se encuentra la base de datos.");


        $consulta = "select * FROM pagosclientes  where idCliente like '%$labusqueda%' ";
        $consulta2 = "INSERT INTO `gym`.`registrodiario` (`idPagoCliente`, `idCliente`, `idTipoPeriodo`, `inicio`, `final`,  `costo`) select * FROM pagosclientes  where idCliente like '%$labusqueda%' AND curdate() < final ";

        $resultados = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
        $resultados2 = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta2);
        $filas = array(); // Crea la variable $filas y se le asigna un array vacío
        // (Si la consulta no devuelve ningún resultado, la función por lo menos va a retornar un array vacío)

        while ($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($resultados, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            $filas[] = $fila; // Añade el array $fila al final de $filas
        }

        mysqli_close($conexion);

        return $filas; // Devuelve el array $filas
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Sistema de historias médicas - Dr. Darling Davila</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <?php
        $mibusqueda=$_GET["buscar"];

        $mipag=$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];

        if ($mibusqueda!=null) {
            $pacientes = ejecuta_consulta($mibusqueda);
    ?>

        <div id="main-container">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>idPagoCliente</th>
                        <th>idCliente</th>
                        <th>idTipoPeriodo</th>
                        <th>inicio</th>
                        <th>final</th>
                        <th>costo</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                    // Si la variable $pacientes esta definida y no está vacía
                    if (isset($pacientes) && !empty($pacientes)) {
                        // Recorre cada $paciente dentro del array $pacientes
                        foreach ($pacientes as $paciente) {
                            ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['idPagoCliente'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['idCliente'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['idTipoPeriodo'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['inicio'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['final'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['costo'] ?></td>

                        </tr>
                    <?php
                        }
                    } ?>
                </tbody>
        </div>
    <?php
        } else {
            echo ("<form action='". $mipag . "' method='GET'>

                    <h2>Busqueda de paciente</h2>
                    <div class='contenedor'>
                    <input type='text' name='buscar' class='input-100 text-center inline-block col-md-6 btn-enviar espacio-arriba'></label>

                    <input type='submit' name='enviando' value='Consulta' class='text-center inline-block col-md-12 espacio-arriba btn-enviar'>
                </div>
                </form>");
        }
     ?>

</body>

</html>
```